# Convert dot notation keys to tree-structured YAML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml, rails-i18n

I've sent my I18n files to be translated by a third party. Since my translator is not computer savvy we made a spreadsheet with the keys, they where sent in dot notation and the values translated.

For example:

```
es.models.parent: "Pariente"
es.models.teacher: "Profesor"
es.models.school: "Colegio"
```

How can I move that into a YAML file?

UPDATE: Just like @tadman said, this *already is YAML*. So if you are with the, you are just fine.

So we will focus this question if you would like to have the tree structure for YAML.

Comment: That is YAML, so there's not much work to do.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just never saw that format before, more used to the tree-ish structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is transform this into a Hash.

So the previous info moved into this:

```
tr = {}
tr["es.models.parent"]  = "Pariente"
tr["es.models.teacher"] = "Profesor"
tr["es.models.school"]  = "Colegio"
```

Then we just advanced creating a deeper hash.

```
result = {} #The resulting hash

tr.each do |k, value|
  h = result
  keys = k.split(".") # This key is a concatenation of keys
  keys.each_with_index do |key, index|
    h[key] = {} unless h.has_key? key
    if index == keys.length - 1 # If its the last element
      h[key] = value            # then we only need to set the value
    else
      h = h[key]
    end
  end
end;

require 'yaml'

puts result.to_yaml #Here it is for your YAMLing pleasure
```